# Why is this Web Service called from Matlab receiving null?

Tags: matlab, web-services, soap

I have created a very basic Web Service "operation" with an operation called "hello". It works perfectly from SoapUI, but when I use **Matlab 2014a** to call it, the input parameters are never obtained. So hello() always returns "Hello null!" and other operations, such as addition(), always returns 0. I have followed Matlab help and I am unable to see what is going on.

What I have done is:

```
>> createClassFromWsdl('http://ip/WebServiceTest/operation?wsdl')
ans = operation
>> obj = operation
endpoint: 'http://ip/WebServiceTest/operation'
      wsdl: 'http://ip/WebServiceTest/operation?wsdl'
>> methods(obj)
addition         display     hello        operation
>> hello(obj, 'John')
ans =

Hello null!
```

This demonstrates that the Web Service is called correctly and it returns an answer, but the input parameter is not obtained.

The generated code `hello.m` seems fine to me:

```
function xReturn = hello(obj,name)
%hello(obj,name)
%
%     Input:
%       name = (string)
%   
%     Output:
%       return = (string)

% Build up the argument lists.
values = { ...
   name, ...
   };
names = { ...
   'name', ...
   };
types = { ...
   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string', ...
   };

% Create the message, make the call, and convert the response into a variable.
soapMessage = createSoapMessage( ...
    'http://webservices/', ...
    'hello', ...
    values,names,types,'document');
response = callSoapService( ...
    obj.endpoint, ...
    '', ...
    soapMessage);
xReturn = parseSoapResponse(response);
```

I have captured network traffic to see the SOAP message and Matlab sends indeed the parameter, and the message looks fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <hello xmlns="http://webservices/">
         <name xsi:type="xs:string">John</name>
      </hello>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The same message from SoapUI, which returns a correct *Hello John!* value would look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:hello>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <name>John</name>
      </web:hello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What is it happening?

---

**EDIT**

I have also found this in the logs:

```
Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I believe this is due to an error on old Matlab Web Service implementation, especially related to the lack of explicit namespace here `<hello xmlns="http://webservices/">`

From version 2014b there is [a new way to call Web Services](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/access-services-that-use-wsdl-documents.html) based on JDK and Apache CXF, and using the Web Services are called correctly. According to the documentation, the steps are:

> 1. Install and/or locate the Java JDK and Apache CXF programs.
> 2. Set the
>      paths to the JDK and CXF programs using the
>      matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath function. Values for the paths are saved
>      across sessions in your user preferences, so you only need to
>      specify them once.
> 3. Change the MATLAB current folder to the location
>      where you want to use the files generated from the WSDL document.
>      You must have write-permission for this folder.
> 4. Run
>      matlab.wsdl.createWSDLClient, supplying the WSDL document location,
>      which can be a URL or a path to a file. The function converts the
>      server's APIs to a MATLAB class, and creates a class folder in the
>      current folder. The class folder contains methods for using the
>      server's APIs. The function always creates a constructor method that
>      has the same name as the class. You only need to run the
>      matlab.wsdl.createWSDLClient function once. You can access the class
>      anytime after that.
> 5. Create an object of the class whenever you want
>      to use the operations of the service.
> 6. View information about the
>      class to see what methods (operations) are available for you to use.
> 7. Use the methods of the object to run applications on and exchange
>      data with the server. MATLAB automatically converts XML data types
>      to MATLAB types, and vice versa.

**Note:** Depending on the version of Matlab used you might be required to provide a minimum or specific version of JDK

An example can be:

```
jdk = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79'
cxf = 'C:\Program Files\apache\apache-cxf-2.7.18'
matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath('JDK',jdk,'CXF',cxf)
matlab.wsdl.createWSDLClient('http://ip/WebServiceTest/operation?wsdl')
javaaddpath('.\+wsdl\operation.jar')
obj = operation
methods(obj)
hello(obj, 'John')
```

The newer version produces the following SOAP message:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:hello xmlns:ns2="http://webservices/">
            <name>John</name>
        </ns2:hello>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```